# Access android application database on device (permission denied)

Tags: android, sqlite

I can't access my application database on my device.

I tried these commands:

/# adb shell

/# sqlite3 /data/data/ANDROID.SQLite/databases/notes.db

but I always get a permission denied message!

I also tried to copy the database to my sdcard but still I can't have access to it from adb shell.

Any solutions please??

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only do that on a rooted android device.

Alternatively, you may do this on the emulator which gives you access to that data for debugging SQLite database entries.

Comment: how can i access my device with root privileges ?

Comment: Just root it, then you'll have full access.

Comment: You will need to search for that elsewhere in the forums or other stackoverflow posts as it can be device specific.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the permission. If you only need to read the database and not modify it or store it, you can do it in a easy way. First root your device. You can find a ton of tutorials to how to root your device. I prefer KingRoot. Afterwards go to the Play Store and download a SQLite Reader or Manager to access the database directly from your device. Since I only need to read the databases on my project and confirm their existence, I prefer SQLite DB Reader by AndroLd.